# Why e.preventDefault() does not work in React?

Tags: reactjs, form-submit

Basic code below, yet the form submits and reloads. Why?

```
import React from 'react';

class TestSubmitComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    formSubmitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); //should prevent submit, and continue below?
        console.log(e);

        console.log('hello world ! why this does NOT show in console?!')
        return false;
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <form method="POST" action="/">
                <div onSubmit={this.formSubmitHandler}>
                    <h1>Select a file to upload</h1>

                    <input type="file" accept=".txt" name="ctlFileInput"></input>

                    <p/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Click to submit" />
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default TestSubmitComponent;
```

Comment: What happens when you move onSubmit attribute from div to the form?

Comment: oh !! slight oversight.. i added the form tags later but left onSubmit at div tag. Accepted if you make it an answer !

Comment: @techgyani.. if you make your comment an answer, i will accept it. because you answered first within a few mins of me asking the question.

Comment: @joedotnet I have added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onSubmit is written as the attribute of the div element after form therefore it was not working as expected. Page is loading after form submit because form's submit event was uncontrolled.

If you will move it to the form element then it will work.

Example

```
<form method="POST" action="/" onSubmit={this.formSubmitHandler}>
                <div>
                    <h1>Select a file to upload</h1>

                    <input type="file" accept=".txt" name="ctlFileInput"></input>

                    <p/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Click to submit" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `formSubmitHandler()` method **isn't actually triggered** so the *default behavior of a page refresh is occurring* on each form submission since the `onSubmit()` callback needs to be tied to your `form` element:

```
 <form onSubmit={this.formSubmitHandler}>
```

Additionally, I would remove the `POST` request to the `/` route on your server. This is defined within your `form` element but this isn't desired since this will *make a call to your server, instead of trigger your `formSubmitHandler()` method*. Maybe you could try something along the lines of:

```
import React from 'react';

class TestSubmitComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    formSubmitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); //should prevent submit, and continue below?
        console.log(e);
        console.log('hello world ! why this does NOT show in console?!')
        return false;
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.formSubmitHandler}>
                <div>
                    <h1>Select a file to upload</h1>

                    <input type="file" accept=".txt" name="ctlFileInput"></input>

                    <p/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Click to submit" />
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default TestSubmitComponent;
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Is it necessary to bind the arrow function?

Comment: @Cerberus good callout, I missed that it was an arrow function. But no since it's an arrow function that isn't necessary. I will adjust my answer